# Show that $|\cdot|:L(E;F)\to \mathbb{R}$ is a norm under $L(E;F)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

The question is as follows:

Let $E,F,G$ be normed vector spaces. Show that:

The application (maybe 'transformation' in English?) $|\cdot|:L(E;F)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by:

$$|T| = \sup\{|T\cdot x|; x\in E, |x|=1\}$$

is a norm under $L(E;F)$

First of all, how can an application (transformation?) in $L(E;F)$ make sense? $L(E;F)$ is the space of all transformations from $E$ to $F$. Does it mean that $|\cdot|$ takes one transformation from $E$ to $F$ and does that sup thing?

By following this definition, I'm trying to think in how that definition is a norm in $L(E;F)$:

If $|T| = 0$, then $\sup\{|T\cdot x|\} =\cdots$

How can I arrive here that $T=0$?

Also, $|T|$ is always $\ge 0$ because is defined as another norm (or better, the sup of it)

Also, how to prove the triangle inequality?

**UPDATE**:

What's the point saying that it will define the application $|\cdot|$ but then defining $|T|$?

I'm asking this because if later asks me to prove

$$|S\circ T|\le |S|\cdot |T|$$

but what is $|S|\cdot |T|$? And what is $|S\circ T|$?

Comment: It’s always more precise to write
$$
\| T \|_{L(E,F)} \stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
\sup(\{ \| T(x) \|_{F} \mid x \in E ~ \text{and} ~ \| x \|_{E} = 1 \}).
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, when you want to define an application $f:X\to Y$, you pick an element $x\in X$ and say which element is $f(x)$. That's what we're doing. We pick a $T\in L(E,F)$ and say what $|T|$ means.

Now, to define $|T|$ for $T\in L(E,F)$, we pick all the values $|T(x)|$ with $x\in E$ such that $|x|=1$, and calculate the supremum. For example, if we take the identity map $I:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, then the only elements in $\mathbb R$ that satisfy $|x|=1$ are $\pm1$. And $|I(1)|=|I(-1)|=1$, so $|I|=1$.

---

When I write $T(x)$ I'm considering $T$ as an application from $E$ to $F$. So $T$ picks elements of $E$, say, $x$, and gives an element of $Y$ which is commonly written $T(x)$ or $Tx$. When you write $T\cdot x$, you are kind of using the matrix notation, which is perfectly fine.

---

Let's first recall some properties of supremums. Let $A$ and $B$ be bounded subsets of $\mathbb R$, so they have supremum and infimum. Let's define

$$A+B=\{a+b: a\in A, b\in B\}$$
$$\lambda\cdot A=\{\lambda a: a\in A\}$$

for $\lambda\in \mathbb R$.

1. *If $a\in A$, then $a\leq \sup A$.*
2. *If a real number $M$ satisfies $a\leq M$ for all $a\in A$, then $\sup A\leq M$.*
3. *If $\lambda>0$, then $\lambda\cdot A$ is bounded and $\sup \lambda A=\lambda\cdot \sup A$.*
4. *$A+B$ is bounded and $\sup (A+B)=\sup A + \sup B$.*

Proofs: 1. and 2. are obvious from the definition of supremum, remember that $\sup A$ is the least upper bound for $A$. You can try to do 3 on your own. Now, 4 is a bit tricky, it helps if you first prove it for the particular case $B=\{b\}$. If you want to try them and need help or want me to provide proofs, please say so.

---

Now, let's prove that is a norm.

- It is clear that if $T=0$, then $|T|=0$. Let's see the converse. If $|T|=0$, then it means that $\sup \{|T(x)|: |x|=1\}=0$. But the set $\{|T(x)|, |x|=1\}$ has non-negative elements, so if its supremum is $0$ then it means that every element is zero. That is, $|T(x)|=0$ for all $|x|=1$. Now, it is easy to prove that $T(x)=0$ for all $x$.
- To prove that $|T|$ is norm, you also have to check that $|\lambda T|=|\lambda| |T|$. This is simple:

$$ |\lambda T|=\sup_{|x|=1} |\lambda T(x)|=\sup_{|x|=1} \{|\lambda|\cdot| T(x)|\}=|\lambda| \sup_{|x|=1} |T(x)|=|\lambda| \cdot |T|$$

- If $T,S \in L(E,F)$, then we have, for each $x\in E$ that satisfies $|x|=1$,
  $$|(T+S)(x)|=|T(x)+S(x)| \leq |T(x)|+|S(x)| \leq |T| + |S| $$
  applying the triangle inequality first, and the definition of $|T|$ (using property 1 above). Now just use property 2 to finish.

---

Now, if you have $E, F, G$ normed vector spaces, and applications $T\in L(E,F)$ and $S\in L(F,G)$, you can define an element of $L(E,G)$, which we call *composition* and write $S\circ T$:

$$S\circ T(x)=S(T(x))$$

How does this works? We want to provide, for each $x\in E$ an element in $G$. We know that $T$ provides elements of $F$ if we give it an element of $E$, and that $S$ provides elements of $G$ if we give it an element of $F$. So now, let's pick $x\in E$. $T(x)$ is an element of $F$, so now $S$ can be applied to $T(x)$ and produce $S(T(x))$, an element of $G$.

So $|S\circ T|$ would simply be the norm of the element $S\circ T \in L(E,G)$. Explicitly,

$$|S\circ T|=\sup_{|x|=1} |S(T(x))|$$

Now, let's prove that $|S\circ T|\leq |S| \cdot |T|$ (this $\cdot$ is the product in $\mathbb R$, remember $|T|$ and $|S|$ are real numbers).

Pick $|x|=1$. Now, $T(x)$ may not have norm $1$, but we can sort it by working with $y=\frac{T(x)}{|T(x)|}$ instead. So
$$|S(y)|\leq |S|$$
but we also have (recall that $|T(x)|$ is a real number)
$$|S(y)|=\left|S\left(\frac{T(x)}{|T(x)|}\right)\right|=\frac{1}{|T(x)|}\cdot |S(T(x))|$$
so, combining both lines, we get:
$$\frac{|S(T(x))|}{|T(x)|} \leq |S|$$
Now, multiplying by $|T(x)|$ and applying property 1:
$$|S(T(x)| \leq |S|\cdot |T(x)| \leq |S|\cdot |T|$$
and using property 2:
$$|S\circ T|\leq |S|\cdot |T|$$

Comment: but my definition says $|T| = \sup \{|T\cdot x|\}$, does this $\cdot$ means $T(x)$????

Comment: could you be more clear in the last part when it says about the sup?

Comment: would you mind seeing my update, I'd love to open a bounty of 100 points if you could help me on this

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I've made an edit. If you need anything else, please let me know.

Comment: what is the difference between $|S(y)|$ and $|S|$?

Comment: Are you sayign that $|S(y)|$ is the 'common' norm while $|S|$ is the norm as defined in the exercise?

Comment: $|S(y)|$ is the norm of the element $S(y)$ in $G$, while $|S|$ is the norm of the mapping $S$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case where $E=\mathbb R^n$ and $F=\mathbb R^m$. Then (once you have fixed a basis) operators $T\in L(E;F)$ are in correspondence with matrices $A\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb R)$. Since $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb R)$ is a vector space, it makes sense to consider norms on it. Clearly we have the usual norms associated with $\mathbb R^{mn}$, but what about norms that arise from its structure as a linear operator? Recall for bounded functions $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ we have the norm
$$\|f\|_\infty:=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R^n}\|f(x)\|.$$
However, in the case of matrices (or linear operators), this won't do because the linearity ensures that the supremum is infinite. However, it we restrict the supremum to $\|x\|\le1$ then it is finite (for matrices, and in general for bounded linear operators). Hence, this seems like a good candidate for a norm on $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb R)$ (or equivalently $L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)$). Translating to the general case, where $E$ and $F$ may be infinite dimensional, we want to show that
$$\|T\|:=\sup_{\|x\|\le1}\|Tx\|,\qquad T\in L(E;F)$$
defines a norm on $L(E;F)$. Here, $Tx$ is just shorthand for $T(x)$. You can prove this fairly easily (see flytothesurface's answer; you need to also show that $\|\alpha T\|=|\alpha|\|T\|$ for $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, but this is not difficult).

For the latter part of your question, you want to show that $\|S\circ T\|\le\|S\|\|T\|$ for $S,T\in L(E;F)$. Here, $S\circ T$ refers to the composition $S\circ T(x)=S(T(x))$ (remember $S$ and $T$ are functions). Using our analogy with matrices, we often abbreviate to $ST$. To show this, we must show that for every $x\in E$ with $\|x\|\le1$, we have
$$\|STx\|\le\|S\|\|T\|.$$
Do this in steps. Since $\|x\|\le1$, $\|Tx\|\le\|T\|$ by definition. Hence $\|\frac1{\|T\|}Tx\|\le1$, so $\|S(\frac1{\|T\|}Tx)\|\le\|S\|$. Since $\|T\|$ is just a positive number, we may multiply throughout and deduce $\|STx\|\le\|S\|\|T\|$. You should also verify this is true when $\|T\|=0$ but this is easy. Once you have become more comfortable with this topic you may simply write $\|Tx\|\le\|T\|\|x\|$ for all $x\in E$, which simplifies proofs somewhat.

Comment: What is that norm with an infinity below it, and what you mean by linearity ensuring the supremum is infinite?

Comment: If $\|Tx\|=\alpha>0$, then $\|Tnx\|=n\alpha\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. The infinity norm is literally what I wrote it is (I was defining it). I find it surprising that you are learning about norms on $L(E;F)$ and yet have never even seen the infinity norm...